# Draw diagonals of an n-gon, effectively

Tags: math, optimization, polygon

So i got this problem while practicing python, but i guess it applies to all languages. I am to draw all the diagonals in a regular n-gon and that is fine, I managed to do that. But, there is another criteria aswell, the same line isn't to be drawn more than once. The way I interpret this is that the turtle (I use turtle graphics btw) cannot travel the between the same two corners twice, and not just that you are to lift the pen. I have been trying too find a solution to this for a while now but I can't seem to figure it out and have started to wonder if it is even possible.

Do anyone on here know if it is possible to do for all n-gons? And if it is, could you give me a hint?

Here are two regular n-gons for those who don't know what that is.
(I sure as hell didn't)

[Nonagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eREH0.png)

[Octagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BICWZ.png)

/Q

*EDIT*

Thanks to John Kahn i was able to do the solvable part, as he pointed out it can only be done on regular n-gons of an uneven degree. 
Here is the code for my solution. What do you think?

```
def nhorning(r, n, ):

    if n % 2 == 0:
        print("It can't be done")
        return None
    angl = (2 * pi) / n  # angle for calculating all the coordinates of the n-gon
    a = {}  # contains the destinations for each corners diagonals
    cord = {}  # contains the coordinates of each corner
    for x in range(n):
        cord[x] = [float("%.2f" % (r * cos(x * angl))), float("%.2f" % (r * sin(x * angl)))]  # all corners coordinates
    for i in range(n):  # the diagonals that are to be drawn from the corner "i"
        a[i] = [x for x in range(n)]
        a[i].remove(i)  # can't draw a diagonal to itself
    count = 0
    pu()
    goto(cord[0])  # you have to start on a corner
    pd()
    cordstring = str(cord)  # a list isn't hashable, so making the lists to a string

    while count < (((n-1) * n) / 2): # loops until all diagonals are drawn


        if str(list(pos())) in cordstring:  # should always be on the circles radius except in the beginning
            for i in range(len(cord)):
                if cord[i] == list(pos()):  # finds what corner the turtle is on
                    where = i

            diags = a[where]  # the diagonals not drawn from the corner

            dest = diags.pop()  # the corner to which a diagonal is to be drawn,
                                # removes it since the diagonal to that corner will be drawn

            nwhere = a[dest]    # the diagonals not drawn from the corner where a
                                #  diagonal is to be drawn next

            nwhere.remove(where)    # the diagonal from the destination corner to the current corner will be drawn next,
                                    # so can't be drawn again

            goto(cord[dest])  # draw the diagonal

            count += 1



    done()
```

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

You are looking for a [Eulerian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).

It is possible to do this with an odd number of vertices, but is impossible with an even number.

**Explanation**

"To see why this is true, note that every time the path passes through a vertex, it uses two of the edges connected to the vertex. Because of this, all vertices except the first and last one on the path need to have even degree. In the case of a cycle, the first and last vertex is the same, so all the vertices need to have even degree." - [For a square, but the concept applies to n-gons](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-mathematical-explanation-for-why-I-cannot-draw-a-square-with-diagonals-without-lifting-my-pen-off-the-paper-at-least-once#!n=12)